# US bank account - Which information should I provide?

Tags: payments, usa, money

When a US client ask for my bank account in order to pay me (by bank transfer payment) for my work , Which information they mean?

Routing Number? Account Number? or both ? and is it safe to provide these numbers?

> My guess is both, because the Routing Number is unique to the bank and the Account Number is unique to the account holder, correct ?

Comment: Hi CryptoBird, welcome to Freelancing.SE! Who is asking for this, and for what purpose? As it stands right now, without knowing *why*, this question is likely to get closed as Off Topic or Unclear what you're asking. Please see [ask] for more information, and please [edit] your question to improve it

Comment: Thanks @CanadianLuke I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need both your account number and your bank's routing number. I've a few bigger clients who pay me using ACH transfers. So much nicer than having to cash checks!